# Reading all files in a folder with relative urls in both windows and linux

Tags: python

I can read a csv with relative path using below.

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = './Data Set/part-0000.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path )
```

but when there are multiple files, I am using `glob`, File paths are mixed with forward and backward slash. thus unable to read file due to wrong path.

```
allPaths = glob.glob(path)
```

file path looks like below for `path = "./Data Set/UserIdToUrl/*"`

```
"./Data Set/UserIdToUrl\\part-0000.csv"
```

file path looks like below for `path = ".\\Data Set\\UserIdToUrl\\*"`

```
".\\Data Set\\UserIdToUrl\\part-0000.csv"
```

If i am using

```
normalPath = os.path.normpath(path)
```

normalPath is missing the relative `./` or `.\\` like below.
'Data Set\UserIdToUrl\part-00000.csv'

**Below could work, what is the best way to do it so that it work in both windows and linux?**

```
".\\Data Set\\UserIdToUrl\\part-0000.csv"
or
"./Data Set/UserIdToUrl/part-0000.csv"
```

Please ask clarification question, if any. Thanks in advance for comments and answers.

**More Info:**
I guess the problem is only in windows but not in linux.
Below is shortest program to show issue. consider there are files in path './Data Set/UserIdToUrl/*' and it is correct as i can read file when providing path to file directly to `pd.read_csv('./Data Set/UserIdToUrl/filename.csv')`.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = "./Data Set/UserIdToUrl/*"
allFiles = glob.glob(path)

np_array_list = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    normalPath = os.path.normpath(file_)
    print(file_)
    print(normalPath)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix())
```

**Update2**

I just googled glob library. Its definition says 'glob — Unix style pathname pattern expansion'. I guess, I need some utility function that could work in both unix and windows.

Comment: path with `./` or without `./` are ther same - both are relative to current folder. SO `'Data Set\UserIdToUrl\part-00000.csv'` and `"./Data Set/UserIdToUrl/part-0000.csv"` should read the same file. So `normalPath` gives you correct path - did you try to read it ?

Comment: @furas, yes, you are right. but in windows glob is giving path like "Data Set/UserIdToUrl\\part-0000.csv" or "Data Set\\UserIdToUrl\\part-0000.csv". These path are not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can use abspath

```
for file in os.listdir(os.path.abspath('./Data Set/')): 
    ...:     if file.endswith('.csv'): 
    ...:         df = pandas.read_csv(os.path.abspath(file))
```

Comment: listdir and abspath function are leading me to desired result. Although it is missing the 'Data Set' folder in path. So i am voting up for your answer. Thanks

Comment: just try chdir() after forming absolute path hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = 'Data Set'
datas = []
for p in Path(dir_path).rglob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(p)
    datas.append(df)
```

Comment: Hi @Waket Zheng, i am already able to read single file. I would like to read multiple files. I am using glob to find all files in a folder then there is issue in reading file due to incorrect path.

Comment: @IrshadAli I strongly recommend you to use `pathlib.Path`